# parameter reference using dynamic SQL

Tags: oracle, reference, dynamic-sql, bind-variables

Below statement use a mixture of bind variable, constant and Oracle keyword for insertion. `ABC REVIEW` and `N` are actual values to be inserted.

```
l_sql :='INSERT INTO EMP
         (BUSINESS_DATE,GROUP_NAME, DELETED,UPDATE_DATE) VALUES
          (:BIZ_DATE,ABC REVIEW,N,SYSDATE)';
```

Is this the correct way for parameter reference using dynamic SQL? Doesn't it require additional parenthesis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just esacpe the quote sign around actual string values:

```
  l_sql :='INSERT INTO EMP
     (BUSINESS_DATE,GROUP_NAME, DELETED,UPDATE_DATE) VALUES
      (:BIZ_DATE,''ABC REVIEW'',''N'',SYSDATE)';
```

Answer (score 1):

> ABC REVIEW and N is the actual value to be inserted.

If you don't include the literals in ' '(quotes) then Oracle will treat them as variable and expect values. In your case this is causing the error. What @user7294900 suggest is definitely the correct solution however it would need a high accuracy while putting the quotes which sometime lead to issues. Oracle had introduced `q'[` to handle such situation where you just have to put your statement inside a `q'[` and oracle will handle the quotes. See below:

```
l_sql :=q'[INSERT INTO EMP
         (BUSINESS_DATE,GROUP_NAME, DELETED,UPDATE_DATE) VALUES
          (:BIZ_DATE,'ABC REVIEW','N',SYSDATE)]';
```

read more about `q'` at http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=311

Answer (score 0):

I realized it can use pipe to concatenate.

```
l_sql='INSERT INTO EMP
       (BUSINESS_DATE,GROUP_NAME,DELETED,UPDATE_DATE) VALUES
        (:BIZ_DATE,'|| 'ABC REVIEW'|| ','|| 'N'|| ',SYSDATE);
```